# How to handle validation when JavaScript is disabled in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm using some of the typical ASP.NET's Validation Controls in my website. Now I'm trying to disable the `JavaScript` in my browser to test my application and of course the `Validation Controls` no longer works. I think it's best to try to make them work using one of the suggested solutions down here instead of reinvesting the wheel and build a validation layer for the page or my objects *-Am I thinking right?-*

What do you think of these options and why:

1. Include in clicked button's event a code to check if the page is valid and if not explicitly call the `Page.Validate();` method
2. Check if whether the JavaScript is enabled and if not I should call `Page.Validate();`

If you there's a better way to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation controls are designed to validate *primarily* on the server side.  The client-side validation is optional (see the `EnableClientScript` property).  So if they aren't working with Javascript disabled, then you're probably missing a little boilerplate code in your page, such as this snippet from [the MSDN documentation on Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx#Y1606):

```
private void ValidateBtn_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs E)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid == true)  // yes, it is written this way in the MSDN documentation
        lblOutput.Text = "Page is Valid!";
    else
        lblOutput.Text = "Some required fields are empty.";
}
```

You can also call `Page.Validate` and check `Page.IsValid` in your Page's `OnLoad` event, so that you can prevent a postback from proceeding to the next step when the form needs to be re-submitted.  You probably don't even need to call `Validate()` explicitly — `Button.CausesValidation` is true by default.

Comment: @harpo .. This code looks good and the OnLoad tip is just great. but this is just a rare case to happen (having a JS disabled browser) .. so is it wise to just call the validate method anyway even the JS is enabled and lose the client side feature of delevring an instant feedback, enhancing user experience and also saving the trip to the server

Comment: You don't lose the client-side behavior by properly handling the page on the server side.  Indeed, if the client-side validation is doing its job, then this code is never called in the first place (because no postback occurs).

Comment: By "properly handling the page on the server side" what do you mean ? .. because from your code I think even if the JS is enabled and it validated all the controls and everything was okay the ButtonClick will again try to validate the page and check if it's valid .. I'm sorry maybe I'm wrong here but could you break it up for me ?

Comment: The validation controls will cause `Page.IsValid` to return `false`, but it's up to you to do the right thing with it.  If you ignore it while handling the postback, then your validation rules will be ignored.  In other words, it is the page's responsibility to respond appropriately to the `IsValid` property.  If you think about it, ASP.NET could not just guess how to handle this generally.  But often the right thing to do is just prevent the normal behavior (for a successful submit).  The validation controls will show the error message when you return to the page.

Comment: Then the user will have the chance to try again.

Comment: In the Button_Click event before letting the handler to execute my code that saves the data, I've added a couple  of lines -so in case of having the JS disabled- it checks if the page IsValid. if it is then it saves the data the user entered, if not I call the Validate(); method and return; so it cause a postback and makes the validation controls show the error message even if the JS disabled. what do you think of this approach .. I don't want to ignore nor write a new validation code that uses a different approach of displaying the error message and apparently this works!

Comment: P.S: but of course using this approach will make the page reload to display the errors

Comment: Sounds almost right... you should call `Validate()` first.  Its whole purpose is to ensure that `Page.IsValid` is current based on the registered validation controls.  Again, you probably don't need to call it at all.  Unless you have set `CausesValidation = false` on the button, then `Validate` will be called before the click event handler fires.  But calling it *after* you perform the check is pointless.  Check out the documentation on `IsValid` and `Validate`.  ("You should check this property [IsValid] only after you have called the Page.Validate method.")

Comment: CausesValidation is set to true .. and you're right I just didn't know enough to notice that calling Validate() after the check is just pointless, I just have to return; so it could do a PostBack displaying the errors. "Validate(); is implicitly called after the Page_Load event" I don't know where I read this but since I do this check after the Page_Load, I think it's better to just remove it and depend on the implicit call of Validate(); or what do you think ? .. and yh I definitely should read the documentation on both .. Thanks you've been a great help =)

Comment: Glad to help... yeah, there's no reason to have the extra call to Validate, but there's also no harm.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript form validation is purely for user convenience. This stops them from submitting a form with an invalid phone number or whatever.

All inputs should actually be validated on the server when whatever request is being made is received. Here's the ideal flow, and you'll see that a browser not having javascript enabled is no big deal:

`browser -> javascript validation (optional) -> server validation (if this fails, go back to initial page with errors)`

So even if they have no JS, the page still submits the data, then you can return an error from the server. This is a poorer user experience typically (full page reload, potential retyping of inputs unless you repopulate the forms) which is why JS is often included in validation schemes.

Comment: ya Alex is right , we should always use Server side validation. Client side validations can be bypassed through some tricks , but server side validations should always present.Best approach is using both.

Comment: I know it's no big deal, and the probability for this to happen on any PC is very low .. but I'm trying to save multiple trips to the server. "(if this fails, go back to initial page with errors)" This is the point that I need to know how to do it exactly maybe some code

Comment: And there's no need to mention how IMPORTANT is server validation .. that's why I want to insure that if the client side failed, server side will have it's back

Comment: Right, so javascript is the only way to save a trip to the server is the input is invalid. IF they have js turned off (which is often <1% of a site's visitors) then you'll have to have an extra server trip. Not the end of the world, traffic dependent of course.

Comment: @Alex Mcp .. when I said "but I'm trying to save multiple trips to the server" I meant, after accepting the fact that the JS is disabeld. I don't want my code to validate more than once .. I don't have much knowledge on when and where the page validates it's controls. but I just didn't want to call the validate method when I don't have to .. you know ? .. so the harpo's code is good for the situation or there's a more optimized way to do this?

Comment: I don't know the specific language/framework you're in, but it looks like the best case. The same page loads the initial view and the view that shows errors. The only optimization you can make would be to wrap the Page.Validate() in an if (//Do I have a user input?) {} block. This really depends on how expensive your validation is. Typically some 'present?' checks and a regex or two aren't worth worrying about too much.

Comment: It's all in the tags .. I'm building an ASP.NET web form application in .NET 4.0 using C# .. and mostly the validations are simple, it's rarely intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do custom Server Side validation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx  (information toward the bottom)

Something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

      void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
         if (Page.IsValid) {
            Label1.Text = "VALID ENTRY!";
         }
      }

      void ValidateNumber(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
      {
         try 
         {
            int num = int.Parse(args.Value);
            args.IsValid = ((num%5) == 0);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
            args.IsValid = false;
         }
      }

</script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <p>
            Number: 
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" 
             runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" 
             runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
             ErrorMessage="Number must be even" 
             OnServerValidate="ValidateNumber"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button id="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" 
             runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: . I'm sorry but why would I go and do that ? I get the function of your sample but I mean, isn't this mean that I don't use a client side validation (JS) at all ?

Comment: It is the best practice for a Good Coder to do Validation at Serverside.....It is also better for a Security Purpose.

Comment: I thought it's a best practice not to solely depend on the client side validation!